# Conditions in Javascript Calculations

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In my project the var ans3 is calculated through javascript! I just want to built another script which should auto display some text into the **Category of Ans3 Field** according to the values of the calculated var3 and age.

**Sample example criteria:**

> if ans3 < 5 and age < 18 ----> display: Normal Range,
>
> else if ans3 < 10 and age < 50 -----> display: Increased Range,
>
> else ... display: Out of Limits!

I know that this may be done using conditions but i can't exactly figure it out! any thoughts please would be usefull!

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<style>
#ans, #ans2 {
display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="bodyfatmonitoring">
<form name="fatmonitor" Method="post" id="fatmonitor" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<h2 style="color:#b3b3cc;">Calculator</h2>

<table>

<tr>
<th> </th>
<th> </th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
  <label for="first">First: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="first" size="35" id="first" required autocomplete="off">
</td>

<td>
  <label for="fifth">Fifth: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="fifth" size="35" id="fifth" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
  <label for="second">Second: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="second" size="35" id="second" autocomplete="off">
</td>
  
<td>
  <label for="sixth">Sixth: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="sixth" size="35" id="sixth" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
  <label for="third">third: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="third" size="35" id="third" autocomplete="off">
</td>

<td>
  <label for="seventh">Seventh: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="seventh" size="35" id="seventh" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
  <label for="fourth">Fourth: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="fourth" size="35" id="fourth" autocomplete="off">
</td>

<td>
  <label for="age">Age: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="age" size="35" id="age" autocomplete="off">
</td>
</tr>

  <input type="text" name="ans" size="35" id="ans"/>
  <input type="text" name="ans2" size="35" id="ans2"/>

<tr>
<td>
  <label for="firstname2">Name | Lastname: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname2" size="35" id="firstname2" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>

<td>
  <label for="mandate">Date: *</label>
  <input type="date" name="mandate" size="35" id="mandate" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>
  <label for="ans3">Ans3 %: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="ans3" size="35" id="ans3" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>

<td>
  <label for="category">Category of Ans3: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="category" size="35" id="category" autocomplete="off"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<button type="button" id="calculator" name="calculator" onclick="Calculate();">Υπολογισμός</button>
</td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
</div>


</body>

</html>

<script>
function Calculate() {
  var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
  var third = document.getElementById('third').value;
  var fourth = document.getElementById('fourth').value;
  var fifth = document.getElementById('fifth').value;
  var sixth = document.getElementById('sixth').value;
  var seventh = document.getElementById('seventh').value;
  var ans = document.getElementById('ans').value;
  var ans2 = document.getElementById('ans2').value;

  document.getElementById('ans').value = parseInt(first) + parseInt(second) + parseInt(third) + parseInt(fourth) + parseInt(fifth) + parseInt(sixth) + parseInt(seventh);
  document.getElementById('ans2').value = 1.112 - 0.00043499 * parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value) + 0.00000055 * Math.pow(parseInt(document.getElementById('ans').value), 2) - 0.00028826 * parseInt(document.getElementById('age').value);
  document.getElementById('ans3').value = ((4.95 / document.getElementById('ans2').value) - 4.5) * 100;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just to get a base line, have you tried an `if...then...else if` statement?

Comment: [if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) ...

Comment: thanks to both of you!